# $form_state['redirect'] vs drupal_goto() in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, redirection

What is different between $form_state['redirect'] and drupal_goto() to redirect user to a step in multi step forms in Drupal 6 ? I used $form_state['redirect'] but no redirection happend so I use drupal_goto() .

Answer (score 2):

`$form_state['redirect']` is not well documented in 6, but my understanding is that when it's populated it will [not always work](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7) (see the part about exceptions), so although that's documentation for 7, check that other elements of your `$form_state` are not interfering. If you are working with a multi-step form, it might be that you need to unset `$form_state['storage']` first.

`drupal_goto()` is simply a function will take the user away from the current page to whatever path you specify, and has a bunch of extra features for doing extra things (see the documentation). It is actually called anyway when your form redirects.

When a Drupal form is submitted,`$form_state['redirect']` overrides the default form redirect (which will take you to the form you've just submitted) and thus is calling `drupal_goto()` on your behalf. By putting it in a variable, you can ensure that Drupal handles, in the background, when to do the redirect, rather than you having to specify `drupal_goto()` directly and getting it wrong.